# How do I make sure my podfiles work in my GitHub repository

Tags: swift, github, cocoapods

I'm working on an Xcode project (Swift) that utilizes cocoapods. After completing my tasks, everything worked. I then committed and pushed to my GitHub repository. Then I downloaded the project as a zip from the repository to make sure everything was good. Everything looks fine, but the pods are not there. As a result, in the downloaded version the pods are in red. Is there any way to fix this?

(sorry if this is really simple, I'm just new to GitHub and I haven't found a solution anywhere online)

Comment: It depends wether you included the pods in your git (check your .gitignore if you don't know). Here is a question about wether you should do it or not: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45587084/should-we-commit-pod-files-to-version-control-system-git-or-svn?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

If you did not include your Pods, make sure to run `pod install` after redownloading your project

Answer (score 1):

The question here is basically: How do I make everything compile after cloning/downloading my project.

It seems that you did not commit your Pods into your source control, so the short answer is: Just run `pod install`

If you want more details about wether you should commit your Pods or only your Podfile, and about Cocoapods in general, [this guide](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html) is a good starting point.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. This is one of the thing we can do in this case.

Answer (score 0):

When you push everything to github, you will need to check the “select all files”. so that your push to github actually sends the pod directory and the Podfile.lock.

Sometimes you need to manually go into the proj3ct directory in terminal and type “git add .” (Hope that’s the command)

Check your github repo and see if they exist and contain files.

You probably don’t have a .gitignore,  but if you do, the. Make sure that you are not ignoring pod files. Otherwise they will never be written to the repository.

If the pod files are in the repo you shouldn’t need to do a pod install. But if all else fails, that’s what you need to do.